# sematic ui react , is possible split tabs on two parts?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, semantic-ui

Is it possible to split tabs as in the picture below or I need to use `Menu` component instead?

I really have no idea how make it.

[image]

```
const panes = [
    {
        menuItem: "Информация",
        render: () => <Tab.Pane attached={false}>Информация</Tab.Pane>,
    },
    {
        menuItem: "Добавить кандидатов",
        render: () => (<Tab.Pane attached={false}><AddCandidates /></Tab.Pane>),
    },
    {
        menuItem: "Календарь собеседований",
        render: () => (<Tab.Pane attached={false} className="custom-tab">
        <Calendar /></Tab.Pane>),
    },
]

<Tab
  menu={{ secondary: true, pointing: true }}
  panes={panes}
  menuPosition="right"
/>
```

Comment: Weird !!! After u press TAB from the keyboard from the third tab, is it going to the fourth one or first one?

Comment: @Guru1988 it doesn't matter , actually no one switches tabs with Tab key . Usually users clicks on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kind of hack but it's working. The trick is, to use [custom menu tab](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/tab/#usage-custom-menu-item) and use `flexbox` trick to align the last item to the right (Inspired by [this post](https://medium.com/@iamryanyu/how-to-align-last-flex-item-to-right-73512e4e5912)).

Like this:

```jsx
const panes = [
  { menuItem: 'Tab 1', render: () => <Tab.Pane>Tab 1 Content</Tab.Pane> },
  { menuItem: 'Tab 2', render: () => <Tab.Pane>Tab 2 Content</Tab.Pane> },
  { menuItem: 'Tab 3', render: () => <Tab.Pane>Tab 3 Content</Tab.Pane> },
  { menuItem: <Menu.Item key='messages' className="to-right">Tab 4</Menu.Item>, render: () => <Tab.Pane>Tab 3 Content</Tab.Pane> },
  { menuItem: 'Tab 5', render: () => <Tab.Pane>Tab 5 Content</Tab.Pane> },
]
```

```css
.to-right {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sematic-ui-align-tab-to-right-kxp6km?file=index.js)

Comment: You should set the class `to-right` to the first element in the right. In your case, the 4th.